# Why is L = {a^ib^i , 0<i<5} regular?

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma, language-theory

I am trying to understand regular languages. I found this question here https://www.sanfoundry.com/automata-theory-multiple-choice-questions-answers/
Is `L = {a^i b^i | 0<i<5}` regular?
**The answer is yes but I do not get it.**
Let's take `z = a^4^ b^4` , z belongs to L.
I can break z into  `u = a, v= a^3, w= b^4` . I can see that `uv^2w = a a^6 b^4 = a^7 b^4` which does not belong to L . By pumping lemma L is not regular.

**Do I somehow misuse the theorem ?**

Comment: That language is regular because it's trivial to build a DFA for it, the equivalent of the `^(?:|ab|aabb|aaabbb|aaaabbbb)$` regular expression.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @Progman I think i am not allowed to delete a question once it has been answered

Answer (score 1):

Because the set is finite and every finite set can be represented by a regular expression by enumerating its elements.

Comment: and in terms of the theorem?

Comment: I don't think you can proof this with the pumping lemma. Although you can show that the conditions of the pumping lemma hold (trivially in fact), this does not imply `L` being regular.